# Cache permissions for Symfony2 on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: symfony, caching, apache2.4

From my comprehensive search on Stack Overflow, the question is very popular, but none of the solutions apply to my case.

The problem is with the permissions for both folders **app/cache** and **app/logs** in fresh **Symfony2** installation.

I've tried the tutorial from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup and it didn't work for me.

I'm running **Apache 2.4.18**, on **Ubuntu 14.04**.

When I check the **config.php** file through a browser, it says that I need to change the permissions for the folders **app/cache** and **app/logs**

Status of current permissions:

```
# l app/logs
total 632K
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb  3 09:35 ./
drwxrwxr-x+ 7 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb  2 16:11 ../
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 www-data www-data 617K Feb  3 09:36 dev.log*
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 www-data www-data    0 Feb  2 09:51 .gitkeep*

# l app/cache
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb  3 10:02 ./
drwxrwxr-x+ 7 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb  2 16:11 ../
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 www-data www-data    0 Feb  2 09:51 .gitkeep*

# getfacl app/cache
# file: app/cache
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# getfacl app/logs
# file: app/logs
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message please?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/dashboard.dev/app/cache/prod) '

Comment: I guess you're trying to access your site with `http://dashboard.dev/` instead of `http://dashboard.dev/app_dev.php`. Try with `app_dev.php` and see what happens first.

Comment: If I try to access with app_dev.php I get the same error, but formatted nicer :).

Comment: `chmod 777 -R app/cache/test`

Comment: There is no app/cache/test folder or file

Comment: `mkdir app/cache/test`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102469/discussion-between-adnedelcu-and-bentcoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, for some reason, not all the Apache processes were running through www-data and when it was trying to access the files they were accessed through the group www-data which had no write permissions.

By using the acl package, I only had to also add the permissions for the group www-data and it was working as expected.

```
setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwX app/logs app/cache
setfacl -dR -m g:www-data:rwX app/logs app/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure youve run the following commands from the project root directory. (the paths differ from the instructions if youve followed for symfony 3)

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
```

If you're running Symfony 2.8+, then you need to change the last 2 lines to (to cater for the newer directory structure):

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

Comment: As you can probably see from the question, I already have the acl permissions set for both apache user and running user (yes, I run commands as root already).

Comment: are you sure you didnt run them with `var` instead of `app/cache`?

Comment: I don't have a var folder.

Comment: Yes, thats the point. The symfony instructions specify the var folder by default. you have to change it if your not using 2.8+

Comment: I am using Symfony 2.9, but the structure for all Symfony 2.x versions is with the cache and logs folder in app not in var. The var structure is valid in Symfony 3.0+.

Comment: Sorry. Meant to say Symfony 2.7.9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102468/discussion-between-adnedelcu-and-devdonkey).